# ntfs-3g Failed to decompress file

Tags: windows, filesystem, partitioning, compression, ntfs-3g

For years the logs of my Ubuntu systems sharing drives with a Windows installation have been routinely flooding logs with:

```
Mar 17 11:00:50 kemosabi ntfs-3g[483]: ntfs_attr_pread error reading '/pub/TL-WN722N_100629.zip' at offset 23138304: 4096 <> -1: Value too large for defined data type 

Mar 17 11:00:50 kemosabi ntfs-3g[483]: Failed to decompress file: Value too large for defined data type
```

Not to mention, the inconvenience of not being able to access so many files in the Windows-formatted partitions (esp. the shared doc & media storages for all OSes, which constitute the majority of the hard drive space, naturally).

The root cause of this is known: a shortcoming in ntfs-3g for its inability to deal with (Windows 8?) NTFS compressed files. (Poorly implemented spec: lacking a marker to end meaningful file data, after which garbage follows, which ntfs-3g attempts to decompress, not knowing any better.)

In 2013 a patch has been offered, but it never went into the mainstream ntfs driver release:

http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30142

```
compress-lastblock-v2.patch.gz [736 Bytes]
```

Question:

How, specifically, can this fix be deployed into Ubuntu 14.04?

Can a module be built that can be seamlessly loaded into up-to-date Canonical .deb kernels?

Can that be delivered as a PPA repo?

Comment: Not to mention, that /var/log/syslog files form with errors like above piling up _hundreds of lines per second_, quickly consuming gigabytes and bringing the Linux side of the server to a screeching halt.  Originating processes may be hard to track, but typically I'd suspect mlocate, clamd, smbd,...can't blame them for scanning dir structures though.

Comment: related: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+question/253597

Comment: Filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1295030

Answer (score 0):

The latest `ntfs-3g` driver can be found [here in tarball format](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/) and can be compiled and run on Ubuntu [using this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file/25962?s=3%7C0.0000#25962).

As you didn't mention your Ubuntu version, *and there are no PPAs that currently support 2014.2.15AR.3.* you have two possibilities:

1. it is the standard package in the 15.04 ***experimental version*, (not recommended for production as this is not a stable version)**
2. wait for the 16.04 LTS version

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: 1. "How, specifically, can this fix be deployed into Ubuntu 14.04?".  2. Yes, awaiting 15.04 release in April.... however for some workstations & servers there is no possibility of such an upgrade anytime soon.  3. Thanks for responding, but no mucking around with `build-essentials` allowed in most situations. Hence no source tarballs, etc.

Comment: Answer updated.